# Java error on casting a superclass obj to a subclass obj

Tags: java, classcastexception

I have a stupid Java question, here is a scenario

```
Class A {}
Class AA extends A{}

AA aa = new AA()
A a = new A()
```

when I do

```
aa = (AA) a;
```

I got some error like Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: A cannot be cast to AA

where is the problem?

Comment: Typo, perhaps?  Did you mean to say `A a = new AA();` ?

Comment: a is for sure A but could or could not be AA. I assume you meant A a = new A()

Comment: AA is an A . and I believe it should work, it is called explicit casting. For example, r = (Rose) f; r is a Rose object and f is a Flower object. Rose extends Flower, Rose (AA) is a Flower (A) . so I really don't know what went wrong...

Comment: Yep, you got the right error!!

Comment: Like you said "AA is an A". However your code `(AA) a`, is trying to convert A into AA. It would work if `(A) aa`

Comment: What you may not understand is that you often use explicit casting if you have an AA in A's clothing.  That is, if you did `A a = new AA();` you could then do `AA aa = (AA)a;`  But this is because `a` is really an instance of `AA`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's your inheritance hierarchy

```
Object
  |
  A       <--------- your object
  |
  AA
```

The variable `a` is referencing an object of type `A`, but you are trying to cast it to an `AA`. This isn't possible since an `A` is not an `AA`.

An `AA` is an `A`, so you could have done

```
A a = new AA();
AA a = (AA) a;
```

but you've done the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

> you can cast sub class instance to superclass but you can not cast super class instance to subclass.

**A variable referencing an object can be the same type as that object, or it can be any supertype of that object**

> SubType sub = new SuperType();
>
> ...will fail to compile, because "new SuperType()" returns a reference of type SuperType, and the compiler knows that a SuperType is NOT a Subtype.

Comment: Thanks, but pls see my comment about the Animal, Dog example.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Animal { }
class Dog extends Animal { }
class DogTest {
  public static void main(String [] args) {
    Animal animal = new Animal();
    Dog d = (Dog) animal; // compiles but fails later
  }
}
```

It can be maddening! This code compiles! When we try to run it, we'll get an
exception something like this:
**java.lang.ClassCastException**

Why can't we trust the compiler to help us out here? Can't it see that animal
is of type Animal?

All the compiler can do is verify that the two types are in the
same inheritance tree, so that depending on whatever code might have come before
the downcast, it's possible that animal is of type Dog. The compiler must allow
things that might possibly work at runtime.

However, if the compiler knows with 
certainty that the cast could not possibly work, compilation will fail.

The following
replacement code block will **NOT compile**:

```
Animal animal = new Animal();
Dog d = (Dog) animal;
String s = (String) animal; // animal can't EVER be a String
```

In this case, you'll get an error something like this:
**inconvertible types**

Comment: Thanks for all the great comments. My next question is what if Animal animal = new Animal(); cannot be changed meaning I can't change the line to Animal animal = new Dog() . How will I be able to assign the "animal" to variable "d"? It seems to me that Dog loses the purpose to extends Animal, right? Thanks